# delete selected rows list in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete the selected rows from the list I have in mysql so I won't have to delete the rows in my table one by one. When I press delete, my page refreshes without any php error but I don't get the result desired either. here is what I have:

```
<?php $product_set = find_all_products(); ?>

<body>
<form action="manage_products.php" method="delete">
<div class="page">
  <article>
<div id="page">
<?php echo message(); ?>
<h2>Manage Products</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 125px;">Location</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 250px;">URL to the Product</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">First Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Last Name</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Size</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Status</th>
    <th style="text-align: left; width: 100px;">Checked</th>
    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">Actions</th>
  </tr>
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_set)){ ?>

  <tr>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["location"]);?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["productURL"]); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["fname"]); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["lname"]); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["size"]); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo htmlentities($product["status"]); ?></td>
    <td><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><a href="edit_order.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($product["id"]); ?>">Edit Order</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete_product.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($product["id"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">Delete Order</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

  <?php

  // Check if delete button active, start this

  if(isset($_GET['delete']))
  {
      $checkbox = $_GET['checkbox'];

      for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

          $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
          $sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE link_id='$del_id'";
          $result = mysql_query($sql);
      }
// if successful redirect to delete_multiple.php
      if($result){
          $_SESSION["message"] = "Product deletion failed.";
          redirect_to("created_products.php");          }
  }

  //mysqli_close($dbc);

  ?>

<br />
</div>
</div>
<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return val();"/>
  </form>
    <div class="clear-all"></div>
  </article>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: do **NOT** use a `get` to delete things from your db, especially with the utterly useless javascript onclick "protection": http://www.thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Spider_of_Doom   Enjoy having your enter table wiped out... Plus, your delete link does GET, and your DB code looks for POST, so you've got that going for you at least...

Comment: Please refrain using short open tags ..., so instead of <? please use <?php

Comment: You have some confusion with GET and POST and the differences between them so I would suggest to you to first look into that. After that You will have a much clearer picture of what is going on and know what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Annother thing: the part when you delete the product executes after you allready outputed the product. If you refresh the page the change would occur or if you put the DELETE part before you do $product_set = find_all_products();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also place all the code which is for deleting the rows in the starting of your file. Thank you @Traveller for this.

Instead of for loop, use `WHERE IN`

```
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){

      $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
      $sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE link_id='$del_id'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }
```

Replace that with

```
$ids = implode(",", $_POST['checkbox']);
$sql = "DELETE FROM product WHERE link_id in ($ids)";
```

Comment: this code still has to come before he fetches all the products ($product_set = find_all_products();)

Comment: @Traveller but he is checking inside this loop. I didnt get u why it should come there??

Comment: but the table is already full and outputed. The query part executes after the whole table is allready built and outputed.